# Issues with overriding get_form in UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I've tried so many things to override get_form method in UpdateView, but none have worked. I guess what I am trying to do is like this,

```
class SystemUpdateView(UpdateView)
    def get_form(self, form_class):

        form = super(SystemUpdateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        //here I do some modifications to the form
        ....
        ....
        //then return that modified form
        return form
```

But it is doing nothing.... Anyone have any idea why this is?
I just don't see why this wouldn't work

I do the same modification to the CreateView, and it works magically, but not in UpdateView.

But it is not doing anything, and it gives no error.
The exact same thing worked in CreateView however....

Okay. Here is what worked in CreateView

```
class SystemCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
"""View to create Systems"""

form_class = SystemForm
model = System
permission_required = 'services.add_system'
success_message = "System '%(name)s' created successfully."
template_name = 'systems/system_form.html'

# when system created need to add accountable_team_history

def form_valid(self, form):
    system_created = super(SystemCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    system = self.object

    if form.instance.accountable_team is not None:
        new_history = AccountableTeamHistory(resource=system,
                                     accountable_team=form.instance.accountable_team,
                                     effective_date=datetime.datetime.now())

        new_history.save()

        system.accountable_team_history.add(new_history)

        system.save()

    return system_created

def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = super(SystemCreateView, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)
    form.fields['primary_purpose_business_use'].label= "Primary purpose/business use"
    form.fields['secondary_purpose_business_uses'].label= "Secondary purpose/business uses"
    form.fields['primary_purpose_business_use'].choices = list()
    form.fields['secondary_purpose_business_uses'].choices = list()

    for optgroup in BusinessSystemType.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True):
        form.fields['primary_purpose_business_use'].choices.append(
            (optgroup.name,
             list((subtype.id, subtype.name) for subtype in BusinessSystemType.objects.filter(parent=optgroup))))

        form.fields['secondary_purpose_business_uses'].choices.append(
            (optgroup.name,
             list((subtype.id, subtype.name) for subtype in BusinessSystemType.objects.filter(parent=optgroup))))

    return form
```

Now in SystemUpdateView,

```
class SystemUpdateView(AutoEventLogMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
"""CRUD update view for :class:`~.System` objects"""

form_class = SystemForm
model = System
permission_required = 'services.change_system'
success_message = "System '%(name)s' updated successfully."
template_name = 'systems/system_form.html'

# when system edited need to modify accountable_team_history

def form_valid(self, form):

    system = self.get_object()

    if form.instance.accountable_team is not None:
        if system.accountable_team == form.instance.accountable_team:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                old_team_history = system.accountable_team_history.get(end_date__isnull=True)

                old_team_history.end_date = datetime.datetime.now()

                old_team_history.save()
            except AccountableTeamHistory.DoesNotExist:
                pass

            new_history = AccountableTeamHistory(resource=system,
                                         accountable_team=form.instance.accountable_team,
                                         effective_date=datetime.datetime.now())

            system.accountable_team_history.add(new_history)

            system.save()

    return super(SystemUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_form(self, form_class):

    form = super(SystemUpdateView, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['primary_purpose_business_use'].label= "Primary purpose/business use"
    form.fields['secondary_purpose_business_uses'].label= "Secondary purpose/business uses"
    form.fields['primary_purpose_business_use'].choices = list()
    form.fields['secondary_purpose_business_uses'].choices = list()

    for optgroup in BusinessSystemType.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True):
        form.fields['primary_purpose_business_use'].choices.append(
            (optgroup.name,
             list((subtype.id, subtype.name) for subtype in BusinessSystemType.objects.filter(parent=optgroup))))

        form.fields['secondary_purpose_business_uses'].choices.append(
            (optgroup.name,
             list((subtype.id, subtype.name) for subtype in BusinessSystemType.objects.filter(parent=optgroup))))

    return form
```

This view doesn't do anything to the form.

Comment: Does it give any error? We would need to see more of your code, to say exactly what is wrong. Your current example doesn't say anything about what kind modifications you do on you `form`.

Comment: I edited my post. I mean exact same thing worked for CreateView but It's just not doing anything for UpdateView which I think it is strange.... So I assume there's nothing special in Model and Form since all the view methods inherit same model and form

Comment: Can you paste your whole view, without `//here I do some modifications to the form`? As is said before there is not enough info to understand your problem.

Comment: Alright, I put the whole views. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Again. You have `form = super(TechnologyUpdateView, self).get_form(form_class)` in `SystemUpdateView`

Comment: Ugh, I am really really sorry about all the typos... I've been doing so many copies and pastes... I fixed it. but the issue seems it will never be solved...

Comment: Hm. I can't see any problem. Only difference in your `get_form` methods that in `CreateView` you pass `*args, **kwargs` but in `UpdateView` you pass `form_class`. Problem probably in different place. I see you have many Mixins, I would strart check if any of them modifies `get_form`. Or maybe problem in your template, or urls.

Comment: Well alright. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Your view will be simpler if you move the form customisation into the form's `__init__ method, rather than trying to do everything in the view. I suggested this in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925792/django-form-optgroup-and-options/37926109#37926109) - I'm not sure why you deleted the question after I took the time to answer you.

Comment: It would work but SystemForm is used in many different places. I just want to alter the form for SystemCreateView and SystemUpdateView, and I think get_form is the only way to do it...

Comment: In that case, you could subclass the form for `SystemCreateView` and `SystemCreateView`.